# How to prevent duplicate invoice in Quickbooks Online API?

Tags: php, quickbooks

I have been trying to integrate Quickbooks Online API with PHP in to my website and I have found an issue where I could keep on creating the same invoice.

Although there have been accepted answer in this [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453573/how-to-check-for-duplicate-invoice-before-adding-new-invoice-using-quickbook-api) however it is really being vague not exact.

> ***"If you don't have the TxnID, there really isn't a way to detect a "duplicate" invoice in QuickBooks.***
>
> Does this mean that upon creation of invoice there is no way to check if an invoice was already create via API?

https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/invoice#create-an-invoice

When creating an invoice the values returned under "LinkedTxn" field is always empty

[image]

> ***"The closest you can get is querying by RefNumber ...there's no guarantee that the invoice that you get back from that query is the invoice that you created."***

Still same as first but I have been searching RefNumber under the documentation but I can't seem to find it.

- If "RefNumber's" cannot be gauranteed then what are the other
  alternatives?
- Do I have to handle this on my local or at least add a column on my
  local table for indicating if item is already sync?

PS: I also tried to insert txnid on the create invoice field however I wasn't successful.

While testing on sandbox I realized there is this number, what is this called? Can I use this for checking the existing invoice?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

return body from QBO "Create a Bill" API provides **Id** data.

The Id value returned by the create Bill is the exact information you are looking for in QBO GUI

This value can be used to call "Read a bill" and check other default values populated by QBO after you have created the bill

example: **DueDate** is auto-populated if not provided)

Answer (score 0):

The `NO.` column you're showing in your screenshot is the `DocNumber` field. It's in the documentation here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/invoice#the-invoice-object

In *most* cases, the `DocNumber` is a *unique* field. But not in *all* cases (you'll see some exceptions noted in the docs related to France and also to custom document numbers).

The best way to avoid duplicates is to *keep track of what you send to QuickBooks* on your end. On your end, maintain a list of what you sent to QuickBooks. Don't send it again if you've already sent it.